# vaadin-upload element: Change upload button's caption

Tags: file-upload, vaadin

Is there anyway to change the caption of the upload button from "UPLOAD FILES" to whatever is required?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Initial reply - for basic Vaadin**

As per the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-upload.html) you can use `upload.setButtonCaption("My custom caption");`. Am I missing something?

[image: Custom upload button caption]

---

**Later update - for Vaadin elements**

In this case you can use its [`i18n` localization property](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-upload/vaadin-upload-i18n.html). Unfortunately, for me the suggestion in the book to change a certain part with

```
document.querySelector('vaadin-upload#en').i18n.addFiles.many = 'Add Files;
```

did not work. However,

```
document.querySelector('vaadin-upload#en').set('i18n.addFiles.many', 'Add Files');
```

as seen in their [github samples](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-upload/blob/master/demo/advanced.html#L141) seems to work just fine. Below a sample and screenshot

```
<body>
    <vaadin-upload id="en"></vaadin-upload>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('vaadin-upload#en').set('i18n.addFiles.many', 'Add Files');
    </script>
</body>
```

Result:

[image: Custom elements upload button caption]

Comment: Thanks, but I refer to the vaadin-upload element, not the server-side component.

Comment: @frandevel I was going to suggest making that clear, but I saw you've already updated it :-). I'm not familiar with elements, but according to the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-upload/vaadin-upload-i18n.html) you should be able to use it's i18n localization features. I'll try a sample and let you know.